# MS SQL - Calculating plan payments for a month

Tags: sql-server

I need to calculate how much a plan has cost the customer in a specific month.

Plans have floating billing cycles of a month's length - for example a billing cycle can run from '2014-04-16' to '2014-05-16'.

I know the start date of a plan, and the end date can either be a specific date or NULL if the plan is still running.

If the end date is not null, then the customer is charged for a whole month - not pro rated. Example: The billing cycle is going from the 4th to 4th each month, but the customer ends his plan on the 10th, he will still be charged until the 4th next month.

Can anyone help me? I feel like I've been going over this a million times, and just can't figure it out.

---

### Variables I have:

- @planStartDate [Plan's start date]
- @planEndDate [Plan's end date - can be null]
- @billStartDate [The bill's start date - example: 2015-02-01]
- @billEndDate [One month after bill's start date - 2015-03-01]
- @price [the plan's price per billing cycle]

Comment: Can you show what you tried, and why it didn't work?   Did you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

Heres the best answer I can give based on the very small information you have given so far(btw, in the future, it would really help people answer your question faster/easier/more efficiently if you could specify a lot more info;tables involved, all columns, etc..):

"I need to calculate how much a plan has cost the customer in a specific month."

SELECT SUM(price), customerID(I assume you have a column of some sort in this table to distinguish between customers) FROM table_foo
where planStartDate BETWEEN = 'a specific date you specify'

Its a bit rough of a query, but thats the best I can give till you specify more clearly your variable (i.e. tables involved, ALL columns in table, etc etc.....)